# Размер экрана Android

Tags: java, android, экран

почему то приложение при считывания размера экрана getSize() стало давать не реальные размеры, а на 25% меньше.

т.е. у меня экран 1980×1080 , а выдает 1440×810

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод [getRealSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize(android.graphics.Point)) - он дает реальные размеры без масштабирования.

```java
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
Point screenResolution = new Point();
display.getRealSize(screenResolution);
```